# Deluge error after restart Ubuntu(I need to delete 2 files)

Tags: deluge

I added `Deluge` in `Startup applications` and **sometimes** after restart or shutdown, `Deluge` won't start. If I try to run it in terminal then I get the next error:

```
vas@LenovoZ580:~$ deluge
[ERROR   ] 11:18:36 ipcinterface:156 Deluge restart failed: Couldn't listen on any:/home/vas/.config/deluge/ipc/deluge-gtk: Cannot acquire lock.
```

If I delete `/home/vas/.config/deluge/ipc/deluge-gtk` and `/home/vas/.config/deluge/ipc/deluge-gtk.lock`then `Deluge` starts normally.

How can I set that when I restart or shutdown the laptop, these 2 files to be deleted if they exist?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could make a script that deletes the two files and set it to run at start-up.

Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm /home/vas/.config/deluge/ipc/deluge-gtk
rm /home/vas/.config/deluge/ipc/deluge-gtk.lock
```

You'll need to place your scripts in `/etc/init.d/`.

See: https://superuser.com/questions/155476/how-do-i-make-a-script-run-upon-startup-of-the-ubuntu-machine

Also here is a short tutorial on how to bash script: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Beginners/BashScripting

Answer (score 4):

This is a common error when Deluge don't exit cleanly. Some symbolic link gets broken and Deluge doesn't know what to do. But I do.

```
rm /home/vas/.config/deluge/ipc/deluge*
```

Then start Deluge.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open bug ticket [#2234](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/ticket/2234) that would resolve the stale file issue.

An alternative to putting Deluge in startup apps would be to run the daemon in the background using [upstart script](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/InitScript/Ubuntu%2011.04+%20%28Upstart%20Job%29) and then connect with [thinclient](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/ThinClient).